# angular: load details in new page

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

i have angular behaviour outside a ng-view. how can i get open a new page
where that view is then located in?

```
<div ng-controller="JobCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="produktion" value="produktion">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:produktion">
     <a href="jobs#/{{job.id}}"> {{job.name}}</a> (Hamburg)
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Onclick i would like to get the details rendered on a complete different page in my webapp.
how can i achieve this?

here is my url mapping for now:

```
when('/jobs/:jobId', {templateUrl: 'partials/job-detail', controller: JobDetailCtrl}).
```

if you need more code, pls let me know

Comment: define `different page`. You have syntax error in `href`...doesn't match route path. Should be `<a href="#/jobs/{{job.id}}">`

Comment: sry i was too lazy, went over it, included it all now inside tje view and everything is fine. that was way too much outside the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't think I completely understand your requirement, but You need to add another route and in the new route's template use can you the behavior....

I am not sure if this answers you question. If not, put up the code on jslint or plunker etc